# How do I clear an NA flag for a posix value?

Tags: r

Sample data in `csv` format. Save in a file `broken_posix.csv`

```
Date
3/10/2012 23:00
3/11/2012 0:00
3/11/2012 1:00
3/11/2012 2:00
3/11/2012 3:00
3/11/2012 4:00
3/11/2012 5:00
3/11/2012 6:00
3/11/2012 7:00
3/11/2012 8:00
3/11/2012 9:00
3/11/2012 10:00
3/11/2012 11:00
3/11/2012 12:00
3/11/2012 13:00
3/11/2012 14:00
3/11/2012 15:00
3/11/2012 16:00
3/11/2012 17:00
3/11/2012 18:00
3/11/2012 19:00
3/11/2012 20:00
3/11/2012 21:00
3/11/2012 22:00
3/11/2012 23:00
3/12/2012 0:00
3/12/2012 1:00
3/12/2012 2:00
3/12/2012 3:00
3/12/2012 4:00
3/12/2012 5:00
3/12/2012 6:00
3/12/2012 7:00
3/12/2012 8:00
3/12/2012 9:00
3/12/2012 10:00
3/12/2012 11:00
```

So I have this file `broken_posix.csv`. I can read the file just fine with

```
a_var <- read.csv("broken_posix.csv")
```

Then I can convert it to `posix` using

```
a_var_posixct = as.POSIXct(strptime( as.character( a_var$Date) , '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
```

or with

```
a_var_posixlt = strptime(as.character( a_var$Date) , '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

The problem occurs now though because when I use posixct, then I get 4 NA values in my string every year. When I use `posixlt` I get one `NA` value on `March 11,2012 at 2 (daylight savings time)`

You'll see what I mean when you run

```
which(is.na(a_var_posixct))
which(is.na(a_var_posixlt))

a_var_posixct[4]
a_var_posixlt[4]
```

The fourth value is always a `NA` value whenever you apply an operation even though it is clearly a date value for posixlt.

I've tried omitting the value only to end up messing up the rest of the posix string.
I've tried setting the posix string as itself, in an attempt to clear the NA flag, to no effect.
I've even tried setting it as a character value only to lose the hour and minute formatting.

I think that this situation occurs because of daylight savings time. It's very frustrating to deal with because when I try to run other functions on the dates I have to try to avoid the NA values since I can't change them. I could aggregate the data by day, and or just use date objects but that doesn't seem like the right method.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with R version 2.14.1, either with this csv and code or with the shortcut `as.POSIXlt(strptime("3/11/2012 2:00", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))`. Also, I think in your `a_var_posixlt` line above you forgot to put a call to `as.POSIXlt`.

Comment: You need to provide your timezone to make this reproducible.

Comment: My timezone is EST. Data is also collected in EST. I find it strange that neither of you were able to reproduce the results at another hour on the 11th. Thank you for the prompt replies. I was very careful to try out all the commands I wrote for this question, even creating the csv file.

Comment: Have you tried just the line `as.POSIXlt(strptime("3/11/2012 2:00", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))`?

Comment: I've been having a very similar problem with dates that were clearly entered correctly being labeled as NAs when trying to use `strptime()`. The wonky ones were all values from March 13, 2011 and March 11, 2012. It didn't occur to me that this was a daylight savings time issue, but that's exactly what it is. Simply adding the argument `tz='MyTimezone'` to my call to `strptime()` resolved the issue. Here MyTimezone is "GMT", but yours might be different. Thanks for posting this. It put an end to about 2 hours of frustration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a time zone without daylight saving time fixes this kind of problems for me.

```
a_var_posixlt = strptime(as.character( a_var$Date) , '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',tz="GMT")
```

Comment: This... fixes the issue for me. I was certain I had tried it. I didn't believe this was the solution until I tried it out for myself. In fact  I did try it but only with posixct. With posixct there is still a problem with the daylight savings time value being flagged as NA. Thank you, I will just avoid posixct.

Answer (score 2):

from `?as.POSIXct`

Character input is first converted to class "POSIXlt" by strptime: numeric input is first converted to "POSIXct". Any conversion that needs to go between the two date-time classes requires a timezone: conversion from "POSIXlt" to "POSIXct" will validate times in the selected timezone. One issue is what happens at transitions to and from DST, for example in the UK

```
as.POSIXct(strptime('2011-03-27 01:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
as.POSIXct(strptime('2010-10-31 01:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

are respectively invalid (the clocks went forward at 1:00 GMT to 2:00 BST) and ambiguous (the clocks went back at 2:00 BST to 1:00 GMT). What happens in such cases is  **OS-specific**: one should expect the first to be NA, but the second could be interpreted as either BST or GMT (and common OSes give both possible values). Note too (see strftime), OS facilities may not format invalid times correctly.

Your 4 NA's will presumably be on the hour when the clocks change twice a year.

Comment: My NA's do occur on the hour. I should have read this section rather than skimming to the examples. This explains why I have the problem with strptime and POSIXct but not strptime with POSIXlt. I am still very confused. Will read more.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, but here are some things you can try.

The first thing to check is that your data is correct.  Copy and paste the dataset from this question, and run it again on your machine.  Do you still get the error?  If not, you probably have a typo in your dataset.  Also try the line suggested by David Robinson.

```
as.POSIXlt(strptime("3/11/2012 2:00", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
```

Does this return `NA`?

Another source of weird date-related `NA`s is the locale.  Check what yours is using

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
```

Then change it to a different one.  The available locales differ depending upon your OS (it's a mess), but take a look at `example(Sys.setlocale)`.

Comment: as the OP pointed out, these are daylight-savings-time-related NAs. This is a FAQ, but I don't know what the canonical answer is (e.g. how to set the locale so that time is dealt with as GMT).

Comment: My locale is "English_United States.1252"

Comment: When I try David's solution the problem remains, essentially that command doesn't change anything. If the problem is OS related, I am running on Windows.