# Wrong Time difference in R

Tags: r, difftime

I am trying to find time difference of 5 min between multiple entries. First thing which I did is I read csv in tabular form and then I have a function

```
time_diff <-function(x) {
    prev<-x[1]

    j <- 0
    k <- 0
    for(i in x) {

      j <- j+1

      if(k < 1){
        k <- k+1
        next
      }

      diff <- as.numeric(difftime(strptime(paste(i),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                 strptime(paste(prev),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), units="mins") 

      if(diff == 5){

      } else {
        print("\n")
        cat(" diff : ",diff)
        cat(" Prev : ", prev)
        cat(" i : ", i)
        cat(" j : ", j)
    }

    prev <- i

}
```

But I have two such entries where difference shows more than 5 minutes even though it's 5 minutes. Entries looks like this **prev : "2012-03-11 01:55:00"** and **i : "2012-03-11 02:00:00"**. why still it's showing me -55 instead of 5, any idea.

Comment: This is due to the change to daylight savings time.

Comment: How can I fix this G5W ?

Comment: I am not completely sure.  Actually, there is no such time as "2012-03-11 02:00:00" Because of DST, correct time one second after "2012-03-11 01:59:59" is "2012-03-11 03:00:00". It may help to look at [This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11529297/4752675)

Comment: Thank you G5W, setting timezone solved my problem. Thanks a lot